# Math.Round() Function returning 1E+1 when I passed 10.000 as input

Tags: apex, math

I am using `Math.Round()` Function so when I am using I am getting output as 1E+1.

My code is some Thing like this,

```
Decimal input = 10.000;

if(input != NULL){
    decimal d = Math.round(input*100.0)/100.0;
    system.debug('d****'+d);
}
```

How should I resolve this?

Comment: But 1E+1 is 10, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, How will my code know that, so is there any way to get 10 instead of 1E+1. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1E+1 is 10 in scientific notation. If you want your numbers to be properly formatted (according to user's local) you can use `d.format()`.

```
Decimal input = 10.000;

if(input != NULL){
    decimal d = Math.round(input*100.0)/100.0;
    system.debug('d****'+d.format());
}
```

will output: `USER_DEBUG [5]|DEBUG|d****10`

Comment: Thank you, That was indeed helpful.

Comment: @PrasadVivekKothalanka please don't forget to accept the answer.